# Add List Item to another list

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have two list view. I want to add list item from One List view to another.
when Item add to another list , item should remove from first list.
this is my **EventDetailActivity** code.

```
public class EventDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView myListViewEventDetailList, myListViewAddEventDetailList;
    String[] eventItemList;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> addEventList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_detail);

        myListViewEventDetailList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewEventDetailList);
        myListViewAddEventDetailList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAddEventDetailList);
        context = this;

        String[] eventItemList = {"EventItemList1","EventItemList2","EventItemList3","EventItemList4","EventItemList5"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.event_detail_item,eventItemList);
        myListViewEventDetailList.setAdapter(adapter);

        myListViewEventDetailList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        myListViewEventDetailList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        myListViewEventDetailList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnCheckBoxClick());

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addEventList);

    }

    private class OnCheckBoxClick implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                addEventList.add(eventItemList[position]);
        }
    }
}
```

when I click to listItem to add items it will give error that  **Attempt to read from null array**
how can I do that?

thank you.

this is my error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: com.sabhagruh.ysgoperations, PID: 28001
>                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
>                                                                                    at
>   com.sabhagruh.ysgoperations.EventDetailActivity$OnCheckBoxClick.onItemClick(EventDetailActivity.java:45)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)

also I want to remove Event List which are checked 
I have done this code..
but not working.

```
 private class OnCheckBoxClick implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            addEventList.add(eventItemList[position]);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          /*  adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
            myListViewEventDetailList.invalidateViews();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/



        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code snippet where you get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onCreate` change this line

```
 String[] eventItemList = {"EventItemList1","EventItemList2","EventItemList3","EventItemList4","EventItemList5"};
```

to

```
  eventItemList = {"EventItemList1","EventItemList2","EventItemList3","EventItemList4","EventItemList5"};
```

because you are creating another local variable `eventItemList` in oncreate instead of using member variable

Also add

`myListViewAddEventDetailList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)` after last line in `onCreate`

and

`arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after `addEventList.add(eventItemList[position]);` in `onItemClick` method

Comment: but remove code is not working.. it will crash the application

Answer (score 1):

You are shadowing the `eventItemList` attribute

Replace

```
String[] eventItemList = {"EventItemList1","EventItemList2","EventItemList3","EventItemList4","EventItemList5"}
```

By :

```
eventItemList = {"EventItemList1","EventItemList2","EventItemList3","EventItemList4","EventItemList5"}
```

Your actual code only declares a local variable within the onCreate method and has no effect on the initialization of the activity attribute.

Comment: you add to call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter to refresh the list content